# Separated .css file for Sitecore Rich Text Editor

Tags: css, sitecore, rich-text-editor

I'm trying to use custom styles in Sitecore Rich Text Editor. I have found article, which describes how to do it, but I have to place my styles in default.css file. 
I would like to add my custom styles in separated .css file to avoid potential issues (for example, overwriting default .css file on upgrading version and so on).
Is there way to use default.css and custom.css files at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `@import` rule: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/@import

The only thing you need to do is to add this line at the beginning of your `default.css` file:

```
@import 'customStyles.css';
```

It's still a change in `default.css` but only one and if you upgrade, you will notice that your custom styles are no longer there so you will remember to add this `@import customStyle.css` line to the new `default.css` file.

Comment: @yuri-dorokhov actually Jammykam's answer is much better. You should mark it as correct

Comment: My question was how to use two `.css` files at once. Jammykam's answer shows how to configure one `.css` file. So, I decided that your answer is what I need.

Comment: You can use @jammykam patch and add `@import` link to the original `default.css` file in it. It's in the comment to his answer.

Comment: I actually don't care which one you mark as answer, but 1) you will still have issues with upgrade doing this 2) the default.css is used for the OOTB demo pages only 3) leaving default.css will mean have extra styles listed the RTE style selector which you may not be using

Answer (score 9):

You can update the value of `WebStylesheet` setting in config to the location of the css file you wish to use. The RTE will load this instead then.

```
<!--
  WEB SITE STYLESHEET
            CSS file for HTML content of Sitecore database.
            The file pointed to by WebStylesheet setting is automatically included in Html and Rich Text fields.
            By using it, you can make the content of HTML fields look the same as the actual Web Site

-->
<setting name="WebStylesheet">
  <patch:attribute name="value">/location/to/custom.css</patch:attribute>
</setting>
```

The above uses a patch config to update the value.

Comment: Currently, this property set up to default.css file. How can I add additional .css file there?

Comment: There's very little of interest in `default.css`, but if you must then @import this into your custom css file, or override the Editor Configuration and specify the css files: https://jammykam.wordpress.com/2015/03/11/user-specific-or-multi-site-specific-css-styles-in-sitecore-rich-text-editor/